# Multilanguage component, language is not loaded by manifest

Tags: joomla-3.4, language

I am trying to create a component. I have the following manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="3.4" method="upgrade">

    <name>COM_EXAMPLE_TITLE</name>
    <libraryname>example</libraryname>
    <creationDate>January 2017</creationDate>
    <author>inf3rno</author>
    <authorEmail>laszlo.janszky@gmail.com</authorEmail>
    <license>MIT</license>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <description>COM_EXAMPLE_DESCRIPTION</description>

    <scriptfile>installer.php</scriptfile>

    <files>
        <filename>example.php</filename>
        <folder>views</folder>
        <folder>src</folder>
        <folder>language</folder>
        <folder>media</folder>
    </files>

    <administration>
        <menu link="option=com_example">COM_EXAMPLE_TITLE</menu>
        <files>
            <filename>example.php</filename>
            <folder>src</folder>
            <folder>language</folder>
            <folder>media</folder>
        </files>
    </administration>

</extension>
```

In the language folder I have 4 ini files:

- en-GB.com_example.ini
- en-GB.com_example.sys.ini
- hu-HU.com_example.ini
- hu-HU.com_example.sys.ini

and I have the constants `COM_EXAMPLE_TITLE` and `COM_EXAMPLE_DESCRIPTION` in these files. I don't want to use the MVC classes Joomla provides and I want to reuse the src folder, which contains my classes.

The main problem that Joomla does not replace the constant names with the values, so when I install this component the registered component will be `COM_EXAMPLE_TITLE` instead of `example` and the name it displays in the admin menu will be `com-example-title` instead of e.g. `Example Component` or whatever I store in the `COM_EXAMPLE_TITLE` constant.

I don't understand why it does not work. I tried out with the `<languages>` element too and with `en-GB` and `hu-HU` subfolders too. Nothing worked, no matter what I changed. I installed Joomla 3.4.3 on localhost, but I have the same version on the production server. On the production server with the `<languages>` element I managed to make this work. Is there a configuration option or whatever which turned off the inclusion of these constants? Can this feature be turned off, or something else is going on here?

**edit:**

I checked my old more or less working code. Is there a chance it never worked properly? I have these multilingual texts in the admin menu and in the site menu, but by install I cannot have for example multilingual extension name and description. Now that is interesting, since [this example](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_language_management#helloworld.xml) tells me it is possible. Maybe by the later versions only, I don't know.

I tested further, with the `<folder>language</folder>` it works too if the files are in the `ln-LN` subfolders, but the package name and description does not work, just the admin menu. The same is on the production server, so this is not a config option, it simply is not supported. Probably the version is too old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the relevant part of code in an [example joomla project](https://github.com/openshift/joomla-example/blob/master/php/libraries/joomla/installer/adapters/library.php#L33).

```
public function loadLanguage($path = null)
{
    $source = $this->parent->getPath('source');
    if (!$source)
    {
        $this->parent->setPath('source', JPATH_PLATFORM . '/' . $this->parent->extension->element);
    }
    $this->manifest = $this->parent->getManifest();
    $extension = 'lib_' . strtolower(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean((string) $this->manifest->name, 'cmd'));
    $name = strtolower((string) $this->manifest->libraryname);
    $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $source = $path ? $path : JPATH_PLATFORM . "/$name";
    $lang->load($extension . '.sys', $source, null, false, false)
        || $lang->load($extension . '.sys', JPATH_SITE, null, false, false)
        || $lang->load($extension . '.sys', $source, $lang->getDefault(), false, false)
        || $lang->load($extension . '.sys', JPATH_SITE, $lang->getDefault(), false, false);
}
```

But it is present in the [current joomla version](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/6833955cfbc0f1914751ab4c110b9b4e332eee3b/libraries/cms/installer/adapter/library.php#L161) as well.

```
public function loadLanguage($path = null)
{
    $source = $this->parent->getPath('source');
    if (!$source)
    {
        $this->parent->setPath('source', JPATH_PLATFORM . '/' . $this->getElement());
    }
    $extension = 'lib_' . $this->getElement();
    $librarypath = (string) $this->getManifest()->libraryname;
    $source = $path ?: JPATH_PLATFORM . '/' . $librarypath;
    $this->doLoadLanguage($extension, $source, JPATH_SITE);
}
```

I think the first code is easier to understand.

```
$extension = 'lib_' . strtolower(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean((string) $this->manifest->name, 'cmd'));
$name = strtolower((string) $this->manifest->libraryname);
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$source = $path ? $path : JPATH_PLATFORM . "/$name";
```

So the extension name will come from the manifest.name and not from the manifest.libraryname. I changed my code from

```
<name>COM_EXAMPLE_TITLE</name>
<libraryname>example</libraryname>
```

to

```
<name>example</name>
<libraryname>COM_EXAMPLE_TITLE</libraryname>
```

and now it works properly. Interesting that every example I read about manifest.libraryname is completely wrong about this. The current version appears to have the same trait, so if this is a bug I think it is not fixed yet.

Note that you don't need the `<languages>` element, it is a Joomla 1.5 relic according to the documentation. It is important to keep the subdirectories and the naming convention. `ln-LN/ln-LN.com_example.sys.ini`. The manifest uses the `*.sys.ini` file for translations. I guess the other ini file is used by the running component.

So my manifest file looks like this:

```
<extension type="component" version="3.4" method="upgrade">

    <name>example</name>
    <libraryname>COM_EXAMPLE_TITLE</libraryname>
    <creationDate>January 2017</creationDate>
    <author>inf3rno</author>
    <authorEmail>xxx@gmail.com</authorEmail>
    <license>MIT</license>
    <version>0.0.9</version>
    <description>COM_EXAMPLE_DESCRIPTION</description>

    <scriptfile>installer.php</scriptfile>

    <files>
        <filename>example.php</filename>
        <folder>views</folder>
        <folder>src</folder>
        <folder>media</folder>
        <folder>language</folder>
    </files>

    <administration>
        <menu>COM_EXAMPLE_TITLE</menu>
        <files>
            <filename>example.php</filename>
            <folder>src</folder>
            <folder>media</folder>
            <folder>language</folder>
        </files>
    </administration>

</extension>
```

and I put the language files to subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

The language constants aren't being translated because you haven't defined your languages in the XML file.

You can do that like so:

```
<files>
    <folder>language</folder>    <<< You don't need this
</files>

// Site languages
<languages folder="site/language">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.com_example.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.com_example.sys.ini</language>
    <language tag="hu-HU">hu-HU/hu-HU.com_example.ini</language>
    <language tag="hu-HU">hu-HU/hu-HU.com_example.sys.ini</language>
</languages>

// Admin languages
<administration>
    <languages folder="admin/language">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.com_example.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.com_example.sys.ini</language>
        <language tag="hu-HU">hu-HU/hu-HU.com_example.ini</language>
        <language tag="hu-HU">hu-HU/hu-HU.com_example.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
</administration>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried out every possible combination including this. It did not work. I'll try it again if you say so. Maybe. In theory I only have to give the sys.ini to the admin part, because that is use by installing the component.

Comment: Yepp, it does not work. Does 3.4.3 support this feature?

Comment: Yes, it's the same for all Joomla versions, though I have no idea why you're on 3.4.3, which has poses security risks

Comment: I don't want to be the site maintainer, I just want to end this project and forget it... I am not sure why it does not work then, I'll check later the code of the manifest xml processor, maybe that answers the question.

Comment: and have you defined the language constant in the `.sys.ini` file?

Comment: Of course I have. These two constants are defined in both files.

Comment: I managed to fix it, I'll add an answer.